# No Navigation Type option in blank activity

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a problem with creating a new android application. After I select blank activity, I see the Activity Name and Layout Name fields but I do not have the Navigation Type option. My minimum sdk is API 8, and my target sdk and compile with is API 17.

Comment: I think "Navigation Type" is not applicable to a "Blank Activity". You should choose one of the other types of activity to get the "Navigation Type" options.

Comment: I tried all of the other activity types but none of them had the "Navigation Type" option.